# Looping over vectors

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure, list-comprehension

I am new to Clojure and have found that when I loop over this vector in clojure using a list comprehension I get some `nil`s at the end.

```
(def myVec [1,2,3])

user=> (for [x myVec] (println x))
(1
2
3
nil nil nil)
```

I get the same thing using `map`

```
user=> (map println myVec)
(1
2
3
nil nil nil)
```

What causes the nill to be printed in these cases?

Comment: using (doseq [x myVec] (println x))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those `nil` are the return value of `println`. Every time you call

```
(println "something")
```

the `println` function prints `something` on the standard output, and then returns `nil`. The overall effect in your code is that you see all the side effects (I/O) of all `println` invocations, then the REPL prints the return value coming from each and every invocation (e.g. three times `nil`).

Answer (score 9):

`for` and `map` create a new lazy sequence with every element in the original vector replaced by the result of (`println element`), and `println` returns nil.

You should not be using `for` and `map` to perform side-effects (like printing) on the elements. Use `doseq` for that.

Comment: A little of the confusion comes from the order in which the data gets printed out.  The initial parenthesis gets printed as part of the list that (map (println...)) returns, then you get the output of each println, then the nils that are part of the list of (map (println ...)).  If you switch to using doseq, or if you (doall (map (println ...))), the results will be a bit less ambiguous as you will see all of the prints before you get the return values.  (dorun (map (println ...))) will return just.  Unless I got dorun and doall reversed.

Comment: @SavanniD'Gerinel The things you're saying are vaguely true, but wrong in most of the particulars. Things come out in the "wrong" order because the sequence is chunked, not because the repl prints side effects before values: if you had an unchunked sequence like `(take 10 (iterate #(inc (doto % println)) 0))`, you would see return values interleaved with print results. Similarly if you had a list bigger than a single chunk (say, of size 50), you would get a bunch of prints, then a bunch of values, then more prints...

Comment: That's informative.  The gist of what I was saying was that you couldn't really predict the order in which things were printed, but even that would have been inaccurate given the chunking you refer to here.  As it stands, I only became aware of chunking a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

`nil` is the value returned by println so you are seeing the printed lines followed by the mapped list of nil values.